# Seaport order fulfillment is not verifying signature

Tags: solidity, ethereumjs, opensea

@seaport devs
I need your help.

I have been stuck in an issue. I have been using Opensea Seaport contracts for my NFT marketplace order settlement. All stuff is done except signature verification.

I have created offchain order signature when I pass the signature onchain with order parameters for order fulfillment It give me this error

```
fulfillBasicOrder errored: Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"execution reverted","id":6198412666664724}
```

Can anyone help me out. #support #smart-contracts #seaport

**Here is my offchain order script :**

```
const domain = {
    name: 'Consideration',
    version: '1.4',
    chainId: '11155111',
    verifyingContract: '0x5F50C441A658C4cD604870e00968Db8418A04Fa4',
  };
  const types = {
    OrderComponents: [
      { name: "offerer", type: "address" },
      { name: "zone", type: "address" },
      { name: "offer", type: "OfferItem[]" },
      { name: "consideration", type: "ConsiderationItem[]" },
      { name: "orderType", type: "uint8" },
      { name: "startTime", type: "uint256" },
      { name: "endTime", type: "uint256" },
      { name: "zoneHash", type: "bytes32" },
      { name: "salt", type: "uint256" },
      { name: "conduitKey", type: "bytes32" },
      { name: "counter", type: "uint256" }
    ],
    OfferItem: [
      { name: "itemType", type: "uint8" },
      { name: "token", type: "address" },
      { name: "identifierOrCriteria", type: "uint256" },
      { name: "startAmount", type: "uint256" },
      { name: "endAmount", type: "uint256" }
    ],
    ConsiderationItem: [
      { name: "itemType", type: "uint8" },
      { name: "token", type: "address" },
      { name: "identifierOrCriteria", type: "uint256" },
      { name: "startAmount", type: "uint256" },
      { name: "endAmount", type: "uint256" },
      { name: "recipient", type: "address" }
    ]

  };
  const message = {
    offerer: '0x8c8e240C723F5F850c6fdfD04a1B08598DaF6B53',
    zone: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    offer: [
      {
        itemType: 2,
        token: '0x6af5BD422A4C4399C9297C68b9AC57924DF10bB2',
        identifierOrCriteria: 1,
        startAmount: 1,
        endAmount: 1
      },
    ],
    consideration: [
      {
        itemType: 0,
        token: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
        identifierOrCriteria: 0,
        startAmount: '400000000000000',
        endAmount: '400000000000000',
        recipient: '0x8c8e240C723F5F850c6fdfD04a1B08598DaF6B53',
      }
    ],
    orderType: 0,
    startTime: 1661850138,
    endTime: 1961850138,
    zoneHash: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    salt: '959087765255511',
    conduitKey: '0x8c8e240C723F5F850c6fdfD04a1B08598DaF6B53000000000000000000000000',
    counter: 0
  };
  primaryType: 'OrderComponents';
  const data = {
    domain,
    types,
    message,
  };

  const signature = await wallet._signTypedData(domain, types, message);
  console.log('Signature:', signature);
}
```

Comment: I have solved this issue by changing name in my offchain script.

Comment: Hey @Umeraqeel, do you mind writing an answer describing how exactly you resolved incorrect signature issue

Comment: @SurbhiAudichya In my signature I've pass the wrong name in domain section rest of my script are properly working